# How to remove /public/ from my url in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there any way I can remover **/public/** from my url in `Zend framework 2` ?

e.g:

```
www.mysite.com/public/controller/action
```

I want it to be like :

```
www.mysite.com/controller/action
```

Is there any setting in ZF2 to remove public from url or any htaccess way ?

Comment: I suggest you start with the [skeleton application](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server) and also research [how the routing works](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html)

Comment: You need to change you vhost directory to the public directory in apache conf.

Comment: You have to set in vhost.conf your document root in public/index.php

Comment: @doydoy44, you know the answer? if not then why edit my question here? Stackoverflow is not a jock site. If you want Point then only give ans.

Comment: @spr7: I edit your question because it's about ZF2, not ZF1. if you disagree, you can go back and put the tag zend-framework. Otherwise know as from 2000 reputations, the edits give no points, I do it to clean between good and bad tag ZF, but if I'm mistaken, I'm sorry.

Comment: @doydoy44, yes you are right, i was put wrong tag but in question, already define in zf2. you can see below, here edited by you :- how How to remove "public  /"public/ from Url my url in Zend Framework 2 ZF2

How to remove Is there any way I can remover "public/"public/ from localhost/project/public/ my url in Zend Framework 2Zend framework 2 ?

Comment: @spr7: I changed the tag because it is a filter. If I want a question about ZF1, I use zend-framwork filter, if I want a question about ZF2, I use Zend-framwork2 filter. Once again, if you disagree, put the tag zend-framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via following ways
Create index.php file in root directory
place below code in index.php

```
<?php 
include 'public/index.php';
```

create .htaccess file in root directory:
place below code in .htaccess file which you have created in root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Thats it.
It will work but the problem is Your public assets files which you have loaded in layout will not work now because in `layout` you should have url for public assets like this:-

```
<!-- Le styles -->
        <?= $this->headLink(['rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'])
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/style.css'))
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'))
            ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap.min.css'))
        ?>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <?= $this->headScript()
            ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/bootstrap.min.js'))
            ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'))
        ?>
```

change all above code to below code
**Note:- Include public before any assets folder**

```
<!-- Le styles -->
            <?= $this->headLink(['rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . 'public/img/favicon.ico'])
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('public/css/style.css'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'))
                ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('public/css/bootstrap.min.css'))
            ?>

            <!-- Scripts -->
            <?= $this->headScript()
                ->prependFile($this->basePath('public/js/bootstrap.min.js'))
                ->prependFile($this->basePath('public/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'))
            ?>
```

I have included **public** before any assets folder
This is the best way which i always follow but at the same time if you don't want to do this there is another way
add this line in index.php which is located in site root directory

```
define('PUBLIC_URL', true);
```

And in top of your layout.phtml file

```
<?php 

    if (defined('PUBLIC_URL')) {
      $this->plugin('basePath')->setBasePath($this->basePath().'/public');
    } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to your vhost config files an change the DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot "path-to-zf-root/public"
```

And don't forget to change your Directory path too

Comment: This is quite a bad advice if it is a production/shared environment. There might be other environment depending on document root. Better change virtual host settings :)

Comment: That is what I am saying in the first line. Change your virtual host settings. This is BTW only possible if the user is not using shared hosting.

Comment: @Mitchell , we used the shared hosting.we want to remove the public from my url by index.php files or .htacess changes.??

Comment: If you can access folders behind your public root you can move zf2 one dir up. But if you can't the best way is to redirect the request from a .htaccess and also block the other zf dirs from that file